# .Net ReportViewer change textbox location runtime

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I'm using c# with visual studio 2008 and developing an application targeting framework 3.5

I have a reportviewer and using this report to print invoices. 
I need to be able change textboxes locations in runtime. Somehow i will let users to change layout of invoices so each user will be able print acording to their own printed papers designs ( each user has a different formatted prints, logos, company infos, signatures..). 
Implementing design user interface is out of my questions scope for now, but i need to be able say to *textBoxCompanyName* to position here, *textBoxCompanyAddress* here...

is this possible ?